Neofetch is acting weird after I reinstalled endeavorOS
after trying for hours, I cant get neofetch to accept a custom backend. I tried to search and see if anyone else had the issue, but it doesnt look like it.
Here's what I see when I run neofetch.
/home/user/.config/neofetch/config.conf: line 711: /home/user/.ascii/c.txt: Permission denied

I tried setting permissions for the folder and the file manually, nothing worked.
Tried reinstalling again, didn't help.
Earlier today when I was heading out I had no issues with anything.
Any help is appreciated.
